# C# How to show a icon when multiple window forms are minimised on the taskbar

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, icons, taskbar

I have an application with multiple forms, each form has the same icon, so when I minimise that form the form appears on the taskbar with the specified icon.

However, when I have multiple form windows minimised onto the taskbar the the forms are group together and the icon changes to what seems to be a windows default one!

**How can I make the icon be the same for the grouped as it is for a single form?**

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've tried recreating this on both XP and Vista and in both cases the application specific icon is retained when the taskbar buttons are grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, the issue has now been resolved, I was running it in visual studio and not the .exe which acts how I want it to.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Gee, I was pulling my hair on this one.